# What are the ways to sync progress bar in server side and client side

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, spring-boot, angular-file-upload

I am new to Spring boot and angular js. In my controller(Angular file Upload)I have  --

```
app.controller('AppController_img', ['$scope', 'FileUploader','Restangular','ngDialog', function($scope, FileUploader,Restangular,ngDialog) {
    var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/uploadI'
    });
```

In my progress event in angular file upload controller i have -

```
uploader.onProgressItem = function(fileItem, progress) {
      /*  console.info('onProgressItem', fileItem, progress);*/
        console.log(progress);
        $scope.abcd=true;
    };
```

On server side--

I have used MultiPartFile. I am trying to upload the image to Amazon Server bucket (s3) using putObjectRequest method. I uploaded the file to the bucket but at front end the progress bar of the uploader immidiately runs to 99% then stops. I have tried to google it, but could not be able to find any solution.

Below is the reference code-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadI", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
 @ResponseBody
 public Success uploadImage( @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response,final HttpServletRequest request)
         throws ServletException, IllegalStateException, IOException {

AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);   
String name = file.getOriginalFilename();
        InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
        String fileName = folderName + SUFFIX + name; 
String bucketName = "abc.in";
        String folderName = "xyz";          

         if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                try {

                    byte[] contentBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
                    Long contentLength = Long.valueOf(contentBytes.length);
                    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                    metadata.setContentLength(contentLength);
                    System.out.println(contentLength);
                    metadata.setContentType(file.getContentType());
                    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(
                            bucketName, fileName, file.getInputStream(), metadata)
                            .withStorageClass(StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy);


                    s3client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
}catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getStackTrace();
}
}
```

Thank you for going through this, if you have any clue please update me with the same

Answer (score 0):

Its better you use aws-javascript-sdk for uploading content to aws.

It do provide progress status through functions like `httpUploadProgress` and `httpDownloadProgress`

Comment: Thanks @maddygoround. Actually we are developing a web-app. So I need to save the data in database.